# Can my current boss, at my employer, request the resumes of all that work for her?

Tags: resume, united-states, legal, employer

Many of us have been here for years.  It just seems strange...as far as I know, none of us are applying for a job.  She just wants it to "get to know who we are".  Can she not get our information from HR.  We're in Texas.

Comment: Doesn't seem strange at all.  Why would you not want to do this?

Comment: Perhaps HR doesn't have it... or she wants your updated Resume

Comment: We don't really answer the legal "is she allowed to ask this" questions here. If there is some other question embedded (like "what is the point") underpinning this, please clarify.

Comment: Why do you think she cannot ask your resumes?

Comment: Sometimes they need this info for bidding on a particular contract as well. I have been asked for this at some point from most of the employers I have had. Nothing at all strange about it.

Comment: Look at this as an opportunity to get paid to update your resume!

Comment: Agree with @DavidK, and while you are at it, send out resumes to other companies as well. Who knows, you might just land up into a much better job. You don't even have to feel "guilty" about doing it on company time, since your manager asked for it. :P

Comment: If she wants to get to know who you are, would she not be better off having a chat with each of you?  Also, did you not each submit a resume when applying? Surely HR still have those?

Answer (score 10):

Not strange.

I work for a company that has as part of a regulatory requirement that our CV is updated on a yearly basis.  This comes from FDA audits where the background of those doing the work must be part of a presentation.

As an aside - for a previous employer I kept my resume updated on a quarterly basis.  This helped me to document what I did for a quarter and could be used for my annual (ugh) self-assessment.

Comment: It never hurts to keep one's CV up to date "just in case" ;-)